AttributeError: ‘Mixup’ object has no attribute ‘name’
I am using fastai with timm (pytorch image models) for image classification. When I try to apply Mixup augmentation technique, I got the attribute error. Following is my code.
# Import Libraries and define paths
from fastai.vision.all import *
import timm
from timm.data.mixup import Mixup

# Mixup Arguments

mixup_args={
    'mixup_alpha': 1., # for mixup augmentation
    'cutmix_alpha': 1., # for cutmix augmentation
    'prob': 1.,
    'switch_prob': 0.5,
    'mode': 'batch',
    'label_smoothing': 0.1,
    'num_classes': 4}

mixupArgs = Mixup(**mixup_args)

dblock = DataBlock(
    blocks=(ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
    get_items=get_image_files,
    splitter=GrandparentSplitter(train_name='train', valid_name='valid'),
    get_y=parent_label,
    item_tfms=Resize(224),
    batch_tfms=aug_transforms(
        mult=2.0,                # Increase the number of augmentation transformations
        do_flip=True,            # Flip horizontally
        flip_vert=False,         # Do not flip vertically
        max_rotate=10.0,         # Rotate by a maximum of 10 degrees
        max_zoom=1.1,            # Zoom by a maximum of 10%
        max_lighting=0.2,        # Adjust brightness and contrast
        max_warp=0.2,            # Apply perspective warping
        p_affine=0.75,           # Probability of applying affine transformations
        p_lighting=0.75          # Probability of applying lighting transformations
    )
)

# Create DataLoaders
dls = dblock.dataloaders(path, bs=16)

# Create Vision Transformer Model
model_name = 'vit_base_patch16_224'  
model = timm.create_model(model_name, pretrained=True, num_classes=dls.c)

# Initialize Wandb
wandb.init(project=PROJECT, name='vit_basic_transforms')  

cbs = [MixedPrecision(), WandbCallback(log_preds=False), mixupArgs]

learn = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=CrossEntropyLossFlat(), metrics=accuracy, cbs=cbs)
learn.fine_tune(1, 1e-4)


The error trace of above code is given below.
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-08c8d40b5656> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 learn = Learner(dls, model, loss_func=CrossEntropyLossFlat(), metrics=accuracy, cbs=cbs)
      2 learn.fine_tune(1, 1e-4)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastai/learner.py in __init__(self, dls, model, loss_func, opt_func, lr, splitter, cbs, metrics, path, model_dir, wd, wd_bn_bias, train_bn, moms, default_cbs)
    123         self.training,self.create_mbar,self.logger,self.opt,self.cbs = False,True,print,None,L()
    124         if default_cbs: self.add_cbs(L(defaults.callbacks))
--> 125         self.add_cbs(cbs)
    126         self.lock = threading.Lock()
    127         self("after_create")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastai/learner.py in add_cbs(self, cbs)
    135 
    136     def add_cbs(self, cbs):
--> 137         L(cbs).map(self.add_cb)
    138         return self
    139 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastcore/foundation.py in map(self, f, *args, **kwargs)
    155     def range(cls, a, b=None, step=None): return cls(range_of(a, b=b, step=step))
    156 
--> 157     def map(self, f, *args, **kwargs): return self._new(map_ex(self, f, *args, gen=False, **kwargs))
    158     def argwhere(self, f, negate=False, **kwargs): return self._new(argwhere(self, f, negate, **kwargs))
    159     def argfirst(self, f, negate=False):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastcore/basics.py in map_ex(iterable, f, gen, *args, **kwargs)
    877     res = map(g, iterable)
    878     if gen: return res
--> 879     return list(res)
    880 
    881 # %% ../nbs/01_basics.ipynb 352

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastcore/basics.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    862             if isinstance(v,_Arg): kwargs[k] = args.pop(v.i)
    863         fargs = [args[x.i] if isinstance(x, _Arg) else x for x in self.pargs] + args[self.maxi+1:]
--> 864         return self.func(*fargs, **kwargs)
    865 
    866 # %% ../nbs/01_basics.ipynb 342

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastai/learner.py in add_cb(self, cb)
    145         if isinstance(cb, type): cb = cb()
    146         cb.learn = self
--> 147         setattr(self, cb.name, cb)
    148         self.cbs.append(cb)
    149         return self

AttributeError: 'Mixup' object has no attribute 'name'



